# how to save 20k xml files data to mysql in codeigniter in minimum time?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

i want to get 20k xml files data to my data base in minimum time current time is around 60-80 hrs to process all the files is there any way to do it in less time ?

```
public function all_report(){

$data = scandir(FCPATH . 'assets/xml');

$newdata = array_slice($data, 2);

if(!empty($newdata)){   
$limit;
$total_files = count($newdata);

if($total_files <= 600){
$limit = $total_files;  
}else{
$limit = 600;
}
$file = 1;
foreach(array_slice($newdata, 0, $limit) as $xmlfiles){

$path = base_url().'assets/xml/'.$xmlfiles;
$xml=simplexml_load_file($path);
if(!$xml){
echo "Not Found"; exit;
}

$survey_id = $xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID;

$survey_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'file_name'      =>$xml->ProcessingInformation->RoadSectionFileName,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
);

//$survey = $this->welcome_model->add_survey($survey_data);

if($xml->CrackInformation){

$crack_list = $xml->CrackInformation->CrackList->Crack;

$total_crack_area = 0;
$area_greater = 0;
$area_lessthan = 0;

foreach($crack_list as $crack){

$crack_data = array(
'survey_id'         =>$survey_id,
'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID, 
'crack_id'          =>$crack->CrackID,
'length'            =>$crack->Length,
'weighted_depth'    =>$crack->WeightedDepth,
'weighted_width'    =>$crack->WeightedWidth
);

$this->welcome_model->add_crack($crack_data);

$total_node_width = 0;
$node_width = 0;

foreach($crack->Node as $node){

$node_width = $node->Width;

$node_data = array(
'survey_id' =>$survey_id,
'section_id'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID, 
'crack_id'  =>$crack->CrackID,
'x'         =>$node->X,
'y'         =>$node->Y,
'width'     =>$node_width,
'depth'     =>$node->Depth
);

$total_node_width +=  floatval($node->Width);
$this->welcome_model->add_node($node_data); 
}

//$node_to_meter = $total_node_width ;
$crack_area = floatval($crack->Length * 1000) * ($total_node_width/count($crack->Node));

if($crack_area < 100){
$area_lessthan++;   
}else{
$area_greater++;    
}   

$crack_area_data = array(
'survey_id'     =>$survey_id,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'crack_id'      =>$crack->CrackID,
'area'          =>$crack_area
);

$this->welcome_model->add_crack_area($crack_area_data); 
$total_crack_area += $crack_area;
}

$section_crack_area_calculation = array(
'survey_id'             =>$survey_id,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'section_crack_area'    =>$total_crack_area,
'section_area'          =>20,
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
);
$this->welcome_model->section_crack_area_calculation($section_crack_area_calculation);  
}
else{

$crack_data = array(
'survey_id'         =>$survey_id,
'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID, 
'crack_id'          =>0,
'length'            =>'0',
'weighted_depth'    =>'0',
'weighted_width'    =>'0'
);

$this->welcome_model->add_crack($crack_data);

$node_data = array(
'survey_id' =>$survey_id,
'section_id'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID, 
'crack_id'  =>0,
'x'         =>'0',
'y'         =>'0',
'width'     =>'0',
'depth'     =>'0'
);

$this->welcome_model->add_node($node_data); 

$crack_area_data = array(
'survey_id'     =>$survey_id,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'crack_id'      =>'0',
'area'          =>'0'
);

$this->welcome_model->add_crack_area($crack_area_data); 

$section_crack_area_calculation = array(
'survey_id'             =>$survey_id,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'section_crack_area'    =>'0',
'section_area'          =>20,
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
);
$this->welcome_model->section_crack_area_calculation($section_crack_area_calculation);

}
/*--------------------------------- CRACK END------------------------------------*/

if($xml->RavelingInformation){

$ZoneReportList = $xml->RavelingInformation->ZoneReportList;
$zone_value = 0;

foreach($ZoneReportList->ZoneReport as $zonereport){
$zone_value += floatval($zonereport->RI_Area);
}

$raveling_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'ri_area'        =>$zone_value,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);

$this->welcome_model->raveling($raveling_data); 
}else{

$raveling_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'ri_area'        =>'0',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);

$this->welcome_model->raveling($raveling_data); 
}   
/*---------------------------------RAVELING END --------------------------------*/

$latitude = 0;
$longitude = 0;
$survey_date = 0;

if($xml->GPSInformation->GPSCoordinate){

$latitude = $xml->GPSInformation->GPSCoordinate->Longitude;
$longitude = $xml->GPSInformation->GPSCoordinate->Latitude; 
$survey_date = $xml->GPSInformation->GPSCoordinate->Date;   
}   

if($latitude == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_info($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$latitude = $result->latitude;  
}

if($longitude == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_info($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$longitude = $result->longitude;    
}   

if($survey_date == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_info($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$survey_date = $result->survey_date;    
}   

$survey_info = array(
'survey_id'     =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'speed'         =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->Speed_kmh,
'latitude'      =>$latitude,
'longitude'     =>$longitude,
'survey_date'   =>$survey_date,
);
$this->welcome_model->survey_info($survey_info);

if($xml->RutInformation){

$rut_data = $xml->RutInformation->RutMeasurement;
$total_left_depth = 0;
$total_right_depth = 0;
foreach($rut_data as $measurements){

$measurements_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'position'       =>$measurements->Position,
'lanside'        =>$measurements->LaneSide,
'depth'          =>$measurements->Depth,
'width'          =>$measurements->Width,    
'method'         =>$measurements->Method,
'type'           =>$measurements->Type,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);

if($measurements->LaneSide == 'Left'){

$total_left_depth   += $measurements->Depth;    
}

if($measurements->LaneSide == 'Right'){
$total_right_depth  += $measurements->Depth;    
}

$this->welcome_model->rutting($measurements_data);      

}

    $rutting_data = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'total_right_depth' =>$total_right_depth,
    'total_left_depth'  =>$total_left_depth,
    'average'           =>($total_right_depth + $total_left_depth) / 2,
    'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
    'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
    );
    $this->welcome_model->rutting_sum($rutting_data);   
}
else{

$measurements_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'position'       =>'0',
'lanside'        =>'',
'depth'          =>'0',
'width'          =>'0', 
'method'         =>'0',
'type'           =>'0',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);
$this->welcome_model->rutting($measurements_data);

    $rutting_data = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'total_right_depth' =>'0',
    'total_left_depth'  =>'0',
    'average'           =>'0',
    'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
    'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
    );
    $this->welcome_model->rutting_sum($rutting_data);   

}
/* ----------------------- RUTTING END --------------------------------------- */

if($xml->PotholesInformation){

$pothole_data = $xml->PotholesInformation->Pothole;
if($pothole_data){

$max_depth = 0;
$avg_depth = 0;
$area = 0;  
$total_potholes = 0;

foreach($pothole_data as $pothole){

$pothole_information = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'Pothole_id'     =>$pothole->PotholeID,
'maximum_depth'  =>$pothole->MaximumDepth,
'average_depth'  =>$pothole->AverageDepth,
'area'           =>$pothole->Area,  
'severity'       =>$pothole->Severity,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);  
$this->welcome_model->pothole($pothole_information);

$max_depth += $pothole->MaximumDepth;
$avg_depth += $pothole->AverageDepth;
$area += $pothole->Area;

if($pothole->Area > 0.1){
$total_potholes++;  
}

}

$potholes_details = array(
'survey_id'     =>$survey_id,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'max_depth'     =>$max_depth,
'avg_depth'     =>$avg_depth,
'area'          =>$area,
'total_potholes'=>$total_potholes,
'distance_begin'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'  =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m  
);  
$this->welcome_model->potholes_detail($potholes_details);
}
else{
$pothole_information = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'Pothole_id'     =>0,
'maximum_depth'  =>'0',
'average_depth'  =>'0',
'area'           =>'0', 
'severity'       =>'',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);  
$this->welcome_model->pothole($pothole_information);

$potholes_details = array(
'survey_id'     =>$survey_id,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'max_depth'     =>'0',
'avg_depth'     =>'0',
'area'          =>'0',
'total_potholes'=>0,
'distance_begin'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'  =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m  
);  
$this->welcome_model->potholes_detail($potholes_details);

}

}else{
$pothole_information = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'Pothole_id'     =>0,
'maximum_depth'  =>0,
'average_depth'  =>0,
'area'           =>0,   
'severity'       =>'',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);  
$this->welcome_model->pothole($pothole_information);    

$potholes_details = array(
'survey_id'     =>$survey_id,
'section_id'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'max_depth'     =>'0',
'avg_depth'     =>'0',
'area'          =>'0',
'total_potholes'=>0,
'distance_begin'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'  =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m  
);  
$this->welcome_model->potholes_detail($potholes_details);   

}   
/*--------------------------- POTHOLES END ------------------------------------*/

if($xml->MacroTextureInformation){
$band_report = $xml->MacroTextureInformation->MacroTextureMeasurement->BandReport;

$macro_info = array(
'survey_id' =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'position'  =>$xml->MacroTextureInformation->MacroTextureMeasurement->Position,
'length'    =>$xml->MacroTextureInformation->MacroTextureMeasurement->Length,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);
$macro_id = $this->welcome_model->macro_info($macro_info);

if(!empty($band_report)){
$total_mtd = 0;
foreach($band_report as $band){

$macro_data = array(
'macro_id'       =>$macro_id,
'band_index'     =>$band->BandIndex,
'mtd'            =>$band->MTD
);
$total_mtd += $band->MTD;
$this->welcome_model->macro_band_report($macro_data);   

}

$macro_calculation_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'total_mtd'      =>$total_mtd,
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);
$this->welcome_model->macro_calculation($macro_calculation_data);   

}
}else{

$macro_info = array(
'survey_id' =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'=>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'position'  =>'0',
'length'    =>'0',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);
$macro_id = $this->welcome_model->macro_info($macro_info);

$macro_data = array(
'macro_id'       =>$macro_id,
'band_index'     =>0,
'mtd'            =>'0'
);
$this->welcome_model->macro_band_report($macro_data);   

$macro_calculation_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'total_mtd'      =>'0',
'distance_begin' =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'   =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m 
);
$this->welcome_model->macro_calculation($macro_calculation_data);   

}   
/*---------------------- MACRO TEXTURE END -------------------------------------*/

if($xml->PatchDetectionInformation){

$patch_report = $xml->PatchDetectionInformation->PatchData; 
    $total_patch_area = 0;
    foreach($patch_report as $patch){

    $patch_info = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'patch_id'          =>$patch->PatchID,
    'area'              =>$patch->Area,
    'confident_score'   =>$patch->ConfidentScore,
    'severity_level'    =>$patch->SeverityLevel,        
    );
    $total_patch_area  += $patch->Area;
    $this->welcome_model->patch($patch_info);       
    }

    $patch_area_sum = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'total_area'        =>$total_patch_area,
    'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
    'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
    );
    $this->welcome_model->patch_area_sum($patch_area_sum);
}else{

    $patch_info = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'patch_id'          =>0,
    'area'              =>0,
    'confident_score'   =>0,
    'severity_level'    =>'',       
    );

    $this->welcome_model->patch($patch_info);

    $patch_area_sum = array(
    'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
    'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
    'total_area'        =>0,
    'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
    'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m
    );
    $this->welcome_model->patch_area_sum($patch_area_sum);  
}   
/*------------------------------ PATCH END ----------------------------------- */

if($xml->BleedingInformation){

$bleeding_data = array(
'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'left'              =>$xml->BleedingInformation->BleedingPercent->Left,
'right'             =>$xml->BleedingInformation->BleedingPercent->Right,
'left_right_sum'    =>$xml->BleedingInformation->BleedingPercent->Left + $xml->BleedingInformation->BleedingPercent->Right,
'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m  
);

$this->welcome_model->bleeding($bleeding_data); 
}
else{
$bleeding_data = array(
'survey_id'         =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'left'              =>'0',
'right'             =>'0',
'left_right_sum'    =>'0',
'distance_begin'    =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'      =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m  
);

$this->welcome_model->bleeding($bleeding_data);     
}   
/* ----------------------- BLEEDING END ---------------------------------------- */

if($xml->RoughnessInformation){ 
$roughness = $xml->RoughnessInformation->RoughnessMeasurements->Roughness;  
$i = 0;
foreach($roughness as $rough){  

if($latitude == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_iri($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$latitude = $result->latitude;  
}

if($longitude == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_iri($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$longitude = $result->longitude;    
}   

if($survey_date == 0){
$result = $this->welcome_model->get_previous_iri($xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID);
$survey_date = $result->survey_date;    
}   

$roughness_data = array(
'survey_id'             =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'iri'                   =>$rough->IRI,
'longitudinal_position' =>$rough->LongitudinalPositionY,
'speed'                 =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->Speed_kmh,
'latitude'              =>$latitude,
'longitude'             =>$longitude,   
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m,
'survey_date'           =>$survey_date  
);  

if($i == 0){
$this->welcome_model->left_iri($roughness_data);
}else{
$this->welcome_model->right_iri($roughness_data);       
}

$i++;
}
}else{

$roughness_data = array(
'survey_id'             =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'iri'                   =>'0',
'longitudinal_position' =>'0',
'speed'                 =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->Speed_kmh,
'latitude'              =>$latitude,
'longitude'             =>$longitude,   
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m,
'survey_date'           =>$survey_date  
);  
$this->welcome_model->left_iri($roughness_data);
$this->welcome_model->right_iri($roughness_data);
}   
/*------------------------ ROUGHNESS END -------------------------------------- */

$joints_data = array();
if(!empty($xml->ConcreteJointInformation)){

$horizontal_joint = $xml->ConcreteJointInformation->JointList->Joint;
$vertical_joint  = $xml->ConcreteJointInformation->VerticalJointList->Joint;

$joints_data = array(
'survey_id'             =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m,
'horizontal_joints'     =>count($horizontal_joint),
'vertical_joints'       =>count($vertical_joint)
);
}
else{
$joints_data = array(
'survey_id'             =>$xml->SurveyInfo->SurveyID,
'section_id'            =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'distance_begin'        =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceBegin_m,
'distance_end'          =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->DistanceEnd_m,
'horizontal_joints'     =>0,
'vertical_joints'       =>0
);      
}
$this->welcome_model->joints($joints_data);
/*---------------------------- JOINTS END ----------------------------------------- */  

$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/road_inspection/assets/xml/'.$xmlfiles;
$target_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/road_inspection/assets/uploaded_xml/';

$ok =  rename($target_file, $target_folder.$xmlfiles);
if($ok){
$processed_data = array(
'survey_id'      =>$survey_id,
'section_id'     =>$xml->RoadSectionInfo->SectionID,
'file_name'      =>$xml->ProcessingInformation->RoadSectionFileName
);      
$this->welcome_model->processed_file($processed_data);
}
echo $file.'<br>';
$file++;
} 

}else{
    echo "No file found"; exit;
}       

}
```

in the above code i m fetching details from the xml file one by one and sending the details to my database. Suggest me the better way to save data in a fastest way.
Thanx in advance

Comment: You fail to provide a critical piece of information: what is your bottleneck? the file reading, the parsing or the DB insertion? Your numbers suggest that you're getting a throughput of 250 files per hour which doesn't sound particularly fast (roughly 4 per second). Profiling you code so that you can check where is the time being spent could help focus the optimization efforts where they are really needed

Comment: Also, you've said how many files there are but you haven't said how big they are.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanx for the response my file size are differ from 50 kb - 600 kb.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet thanx for the response, my concern is insertion time which is not so fast , as u said 4 per second sounds great .

Comment: Insertion performance can be affected by many factors. Depending on how your table is indexed, 20k inserts can place a huge burden in the database server as it may be reindexing the table after each individual insert, which impacts performance. Instead of running 20k inserts, you may want to group them (initially try batches of 100 and ramp it up according to your needs) and run a single insert with multiple `values` . This will reduce the indexing performance impact. Other factors, such as your disk I/O speed may also be worth investigating

Comment: @JavierLarroulet now i changed my code to batches and average time for a file of size 500kb is around 40sec . is there any way to do it in less time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be to lower the number of queries executed.
- Execute 1 select statement to retrieve multiple info and store it in a variable instead of executing 1000 small queries. This will increase consumed memory though.
- Insert data using batches. Instead of 1000 inserts, execute only one. Find a good dimension for your batch by doing some tests. Check how much it takes for a simple insert, an insert with 100 rows, 200 rows etc.

Answer (score 0):

20K files of size say 500Kb = 10Gb; instinctively, it's hard to see why that should take more than an hour at the most.

Unfortunately I don't know codeigniter and I can't follow the logic of your code, but if you're prepared to consider a completely different approach for loading a SQL database from XML, consider using the SQL extensions in the Saxon XSLT processor: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/sql

Having said that, your results are so out of line with expectations that there's almost certainly a way of getting better performance with your existing technology, I just can't tell you what it is.